# How to enable Thread Safety in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: php, multithreading

I want to enable Thread Safety with php in ubuntu 10.04. How can I do this? Now I can see the output "Thread Safety => disabled" by using the command " php -i | grep "Thread Safety" "

Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.  Ubuntu is an entire operating system.  It's definitely multiprocess and multithread aware.  Individual programs might not be.  Are you trying to recompile one of the packages with flags to turn on a multithreaded build, perhaps?  Or recompile the kernel with flags for some other MT-related functionality?  Please update the question with a lot more (and detailed!) information.

Comment: Ah - to install a threadsafe build of PHP on Linux?  PHP is thread safe already, but you can install a multithreaded build.  I found some information here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php